# newtype behaviour in Haskell

Tags: haskell, newtype

I have discovered that I can do this `1 :: Product Int` and get `Product {getProduct = 1}` as a result.

`Product` is a `newtype` defined in `Data.Monoid`. Than I have tried defining my own `newtype` like so :

```
newtype Stuff a = Stuff {getStuff :: a} deriving (Show)
```

But if I try to do `1 :: Stuff Int` I get an error :

```
<interactive>:20:1: error:
* No instance for (Num (Stuff Int)) arising from the literal `1'
* In the expression: 1 :: Stuff Int
  In an equation for `it': it = 1 :: Stuff Int
```

Do I have to put `Num` constraint on `a` or something? Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do `1 :: T` if and only if `T` is an instance of `Num`. `1 :: Product Int` works because `Product` defines an instance `instance Num a => Num (Product a)` (i.e. if `a` is an instance of `Num`, `Product a` is also an instance of `Num`).

> Do I have to put Num constraint on a or something?

You have to define a `Num` instance for `Stuff Int` (or better for `Num a => Stuff a`).

You can either do this manually (using `instance`) or automatically using `deriving Num` and the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension, which will define a `Num` instance for `Num a => Stuff a` that acts exactly like the `Num` instance for the given `a`.